# `require': cannot load such file -- rest_client (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building first gems, I want to use rest_client gems for my gems, I have put `gem 'rest_client', '~> 1.8.3'` on `lib/foo/Gemfile`, and this my file

```
# lib/foo/lib/foo.rb

require 'rest_client'
require 'json'
require "foo/version"

module Foo
 # other stuff here
end
```

when I run `rails c` I get this error :

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- rest_client (LoadError)
```

note : I have installed my gems in rails apps

Comment: https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client

Comment: If you are building a gem then this dependency should be declared in your gemspec file. Here is a great tutorial on [Building Your First Gem](https://quickleft.com/blog/engineering-lunch-series-step-by-step-guide-to-building-your-first-ruby-gem/). Also `gems` and `rails` are very different things. `rails` is to build web applications and utilizes gems where as a `gem` is a plugin library.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks, I forgot to `add_dependency`..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try `require 'rest-client'`

Comment: thanks, but I'm using this https://github.com/treeder/rest_client, and I should use `require 'rest_client'`, and also I have tried that before I ask this question.

Comment: Interesting, I just installed the gem to try it using ruby 2.2.2.  `require rest-client` worked, however returned a depreciation message: `WARNING: The rest_client gem is deprecated and will be removed from RubyGems. Please use rest-client gem instead.`

Answer (score 0):

Try below -

```
require 'rest-client'
```